# Partial derivates of a vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

Given a function $u(\textbf{t}) = \begin{bmatrix}c&a \cdot tx+b \cdot ty+d\end{bmatrix}$ and $\textbf{t}=\begin{bmatrix}tx\\ty\end{bmatrix}$, I need to find: $d u(\textbf{t})/d\textbf{t}$.

My understanding from chain rule is that: 
$$\frac{d u(\textbf{t})}{d\textbf{t}} = \frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})}{\partial t_x} \cdot \frac{dt_x}{d\textbf{t}} + \frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})}{\partial t_y} \cdot \frac{dt_y}{d\textbf{t}}$$

The issue I have is that I'm not sure how to find $\frac{dt_x}{d\textbf{t}}$ and $\frac{dt_y}{d\textbf{t}}$. I can find $ \frac{d\textbf{t}}{dt_x}$ and $\frac{d\textbf{t}}{dt_y}$, but I'm not sure how to find the inverse.

Comment: I think $u$ should better be a function $u: \mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ in this case, it's pointless to me to differentiate a vector w.r.t. another vector.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I think you should use that vector input t in the expression of the function. Currently, t are scalars in u(t).

Comment: I think you might need to first establish what precisely it means to take a derivative w. r. t. a vector. A vector/scalar derivative $\frac{d\vec v}{dx}$ is an object with several components. Likewise, a scalar/vector derivative $\frac{dx}{d\vec v}$ will also have components, which are precisely the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v_i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I think I've solved my issue. Since $u(\textbf{t}): \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then $\frac{du(\textbf{t})}{d\textbf{t}}$ will be a jacobian. So the correct form is:
$$\frac{du(\textbf{t})}{d\textbf{t}}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})_1}{\partial(t_x)} &  \frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})_1}{\partial(t_y)} \\ \frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})_2}{\partial(t_x)} &  \frac{\partial u(\textbf{t})_2}{\partial(t_y)}\end{bmatrix}$$
So I believe that the final result will be:
$$\frac{du(\textbf{t})}{d\textbf{t}}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ a & b\end{bmatrix}$$

Source: http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf